# Crash when updating NSMenu on main thread

Tags: objective-c, nsthread, nsmenu

I am trying to update an NSMenu programmatically. The problem is that the code which updates the NSMenu doesn't run in the main thread.  I forgot this small detail initially - with the result that my code crashed whenever a different thread tried update the menu.  I tried to resolve this problem by explicitly getting the update code to run in the main thread.

The code to update the menu is all within AppDelegate, and it looks like this:

```
-(void)buildMenu{
    dispatch_block_t codeForExecutionOnMainThread = ^{ 
        //Need to empty menu
        int i=[devicemenu numberOfItems]-7; //7 is the number of permanent menu items.
        while (i-->0)
            [devicemenu removeItemAtIndex:i];

        //Need to iterate through connectedDevices Array
        NSEnumerator *e = [connectedDevices objectEnumerator];
        id device;
        while (device = [e nextObject]){
            [self newMenuItem:[device objectForKey:@"DeviceName"]
                   parentMenu:devicemenu
                   deviceID:[[device objectForKey:@"DeviceID"] unsignedIntValue]];
        }

    };
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]){
        codeForExecutionOnMainThread();
    }
    else{
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), codeForExecutionOnMainThread);
    }
}
```

Annoyingly, it just moved the crash.  Whereas the original crash happened on the thread that requested the menu to be built, it crash now occurs on the main thread (as one might expect).  Additionally, the crash now occurs whenever the NSMenu is clicked on (previously NSMenu displayed okay - it just wasn't possible to remove entries from it).

devicemenu is declared in AppDelegate as follows:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate,NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSMenu *devicemenu;
}
```

The rest of devicemenu is built in interface builder.

Just to be absolutely clear, the crash isn't in this code.  It's just that if I remove the threading stuff from this block of code then the crash doesn't happen when I click on the menu (instead it happens when an entry is removed from the menu).  Sometimes the code doesn't crash either - but in this case the NSMenu doesn't work either.

The crash I get, when it does crash rather than do nothing, is reproducibly in Thread 1: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` , `objc_msgSend` from `NSApplicationMain` from `main`.

I know - I've only gone and made the problem worse.  I feel that I'm making a step in the right direction though - at least everything for the menu is in the same thread…

I'm hoping it's just an obvious mistake.  What is preventing NSMenu from working when it gets wrapped in a bunch of threading stuff?  Finally, in case it's relevant, my app has no window - it's menu only, and the menu is on the right hand side of the menu bar.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
   * thread #1: tid = 0x1d07, 0x96edba87 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x11e)
    frame #0: 0x96edba87 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23
    frame #1: 0x95aa75d4 CoreFoundation`CFStringCreateCopy + 84
    frame #2: 0x965485f4 HIToolbox`_InsertMenuItemTextWithCFString(MenuData*, __CFString const*, unsigned short, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 34
    frame #3: 0x96378924 HIToolbox`InsertMenuItemTextWithCFString + 63
    frame #4: 0x93e6044a AppKit`-[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonMenuInsertItem:atCarbonIndex:] + 550
    frame #5: 0x94088e76 AppKit`-[NSCarbonMenuImpl _privatePopulateCarbonMenu] + 237
    frame #6: 0x9408fac8 AppKit`-[NSCarbonMenuImpl _populatePrivatelyIfNecessary] + 67
    frame #7: 0x9408fa73 AppKit`-[NSCarbonMenuImpl _checkoutMenuRefWithToken:creating:populating:] + 330
    frame #8: 0x9411b909 AppKit`-[NSCarbonMenuImpl _maximumSizeForScreen:] + 73
    frame #9: 0x942954a4 AppKit`-[NSMenu size] + 60
    frame #10: 0x94397191 AppKit`+[NSStatusBarButtonCell popupStatusBarMenu:inRect:ofView:withEvent:] + 427
    frame #11: 0x94396d0e AppKit`-[NSStatusBarButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 142
    frame #12: 0x93f50db9 AppKit`-[NSControl mouseDown:] + 867
    frame #13: 0x93f48a21 AppKit`-[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6968
    frame #14: 0x94397b19 AppKit`-[NSStatusBarWindow sendEvent:] + 75
    frame #15: 0x93f43a0f AppKit`-[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4278
    frame #16: 0x93e5d72c AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 951
    frame #17: 0x93e006f6 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 1053
    frame #18: 0x000042cb DeviceMenu`main(argc=3, argv=0xbffffac0) + 43 at main.m:13
```

This is where the menu gets populated.  As I say, all of this stuff works fine - as long as the threading isn't there.  But the threading needs to be there for devices to be removed.  Most frustrating.  And thank you for taking time to look at this.

```
- (void)newMenuItem:(NSString*)menuName 
     parentMenu:(NSMenu*)parentMenu
       deviceid:(unsigned)deviceid
       parentid:(unsigned)parentid
         fullid:(unsigned)fullid
{
    if (((deviceid&0x00ffffff)==0) && (parentid==0))
    {
        NSMenuItem *newMenu = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:menuName
                                                         action:@selector(deviceClicked:)
                                                  keyEquivalent:@""];
        [newMenu setTarget:self];

        [newMenu setTag:deviceid>>24&0xff];
        [newMenu setRepresentedObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:fullid]];

        [parentMenu insertItem:newMenu atIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        //child
        unsigned parentTag=(parentid==0)?(deviceid>>24&0xff):deviceid>>28&0xf;

        unsigned shift=(parentid==0)?8:4;
        unsigned mytag=(deviceid<<shift)>>28;
        bool lastItem = !((deviceid<<shift)<<4);

        if (![[parentMenu itemWithTag:parentTag] hasSubmenu])
        {
            //need to add the submenu here
            NSMenu *submenu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
            [submenu addItemWithTitle:[[parentMenu itemWithTag:parentTag] title]
                               action:@selector(deviceClicked:)
                        keyEquivalent:@""];

            [[parentMenu itemWithTag:parentTag] setSubmenu:submenu];
        }

        if(lastItem)
        {
            NSMenuItem *newMenu = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:menuName
                                                             action:@selector(deviceClicked:)
                                                      keyEquivalent:@""];
            [newMenu setTarget:self];
            [newMenu setTag:mytag];
            [newMenu setRepresentedObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:fullid]];

            [[[parentMenu itemWithTag:parentTag] submenu] insertItem:newMenu atIndex:1];
        }
        else
        {
            [self newMenuItem:menuName parentMenu:[[parentMenu itemWithTag:parentTag]submenu] deviceid:deviceid<<shift parentid:mytag fullid:fullid];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: No, we need something more symbolic.  Type `bt` in the debugger console and post that instead.

Comment: My apologies - and I'm going to remember that useful bt trick!  I tried to get hints from it, but I can't see what's going wrong.

Comment: I don't see any of your code, apart from `main()`, in that stack trace so I would suspect that you are populating the menu items with objects that are getting released prematurely, or are some how corrupt/invalid.  You need to show the code that populates the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from @trojanfoe and the hints that he gave me, I was able to find (and fix) this one myself - although I'm still not sure what was going on.

This problem was down to the construction of the connectedDevices array.  One of the items in each dictionary of this array is called DeviceName, and this is used to provide the name for the menu.  DeviceName is constructed, according to a set of rules, using NSMutableString - which I allocate, use, and put into a dictionary in the connectedDevices array.

My understanding, evidently flawed, was the NSArray would contain a copy of the object placed into it.  In this case, it seems not - because when I release the NSMutableString it causes the menu to crash.  If I don't release it then (touch wood) all seems to be okay.

I can't explain why the threading code should have caused this issue to manifest itself though.  And it just goes to show that the location of the crash could be several miles from the nail that burst the tyre.

Thank you all for your help in getting this issue fixed.